# Fetching $_POST from Page Template into functions.php

Tags: wp-query, functions, ajax, query-posts, page-template

I'm having an issue with the order WordPress is loading page templates and `functions.php`.

I have `front-page.php` which has `$_POST['sort-by']` allowing users to sort posts using a drop-down menu.

It's simple enough and works just fine. Now comes the part where I have the ability to "Load more posts" which uses `wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv` and a function in `functions.php` to grab the additional posts with an offset of the number of posts shown by default. My AJAX query works just fine, but I'm unable to grab the `$_POST` data from the `front-page.php` template within' `functions.php` to properly sort the posts fetched by the AJAX.

I thought it'd be as simple as just including my same `$_POST` values within' `functions.php` so it would use the proper sorting+meta_key, but no matter what I do including attempting to assign a separate variable to `$GLOBALS` containing the `$_POST`, I can not for the life of me get it to get the values set in `front-page.php` in `functions.php` so it will sort it properly when calling `wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv`.

I'm assuming this has to do with `functions.php` being loaded BEFORE `front-page.php` within' WordPress. I'm not sure if there's an `add_action();` of some kind that would allow me to fix my issue here or how I should go about getting it to work as intended. I know it has to be possible though.

EDIT: Here is the function I'm trying to get `$_POST` data for from my page template `frontpage.php`

Comment: The request that loads your front page and your subsequent AJAX request are two entirely separate requests with no state maintained between the two, you can't retrieve $_POST data from a different request.

Comment: How can I global the `$_POST` data to fetch within' my AJAX request then? I tried setting it to a new variable and then globaling that variable with no avail. Pretty stuck on how to accomplish this as I need these posts to sort properly so my  AJAX request doesn't pull duplicate posts.

Comment: post vars in an ajax request are set by javascript. you need to pass whatever data your ajax php needs to operate on the same way you pass the `wp_ajax` `action` in your javascript.

Comment: The AJAX request its self isn't processed by a `$_POST` though. I'm just calling that `get_reviews()` function as seen above which passes the arguments in the `$args` array to `wp_query` and then shows the necessary posts. But, since `front-page.php` is actually fetching the `$_POST` variables from the dropdown, it's sorting them differently then what is being done in `get_reviews()` thus the ajax called posts are not in the proper order. The ajax its self works just fine. If I'm just misunderstanding what you're saying, could I get an example? This has to be possible some way or another.

Comment: the request that rendered your front page ceased to exist as soon as that page was sent to the browser. all vars set in php are gone. when you make the ajax request, you need to pass all that post stuff yourself with the ajax request, that's where the post vars are populated from in that request. your javascript needs to get the current state of the page, set some vars, and make the ajax request passing those vars. all of that will then be available to your php code triggered by the ajax request.

Comment: incidentally, that's what the answer ankittiwaari gave you is for- for putting the state of your vars in the page markup, so you can easily read it via javascript and pass it with the ajax request.

Comment: Ahh. I get what you're saying. Ok. I've set the necessary values to hidden input types and added them to my ajax data request. Still not getting the proper result though. I've edited my main post with my current ajax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this. It was somewhat close to what ankittiwaari suggested, but he didn't give a few key details.

When you pass a variable under `data` in an ajax call, it automatically makes it a `$_POST` request assuming you are calling `method: 'post'` So I did what ankittiwaari said and created `<input type="hidden" value="<?= $_POST['variable']?>" id="post-variable">` and then put it into a variable such as `var myValue = $('#post-variable').val();` and then passed it into my ajax's data under `'action'` as `'sort': myValue` and then in my `wp_ajax` function called `$_POST['sort']`.

Hope this helps someone in the future with a similar issue while attempting to sort ajax posts.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of you $_POST variable to a html element or javascript variable in front-page.php like

//html element

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $_POST['variable']?>" id="post-variable">
```

or in javascript variable

```
var postVariable = "<?= $_POST['variable']?>";
```

Now in ajax call, you can get the value as

```
var myValue = jQuery('#post-variable').val(); //if you set value to html element
```

or

```
var myValue = postVariable; //if you set the value in javascript variable.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think you misunderstood the issue at hand. I don't need  the `$_POST` variable inside of my Javascript, nor in my input. I need to get the `$_POST` made to `front-page.php` inside of `functions.php` which loads before `front-page.php` so I can add the values into my `wp_query` arguments. The actual javascript/ajax call is finished and works just fine. It's sorting within' the `wp_query` that's causing issues as I'm unable to get the `$_POST` made to my frontend inside of `functions.php`

Comment: How about using 'init' hook? add_action('init', 'my_function');

function my_function(){
   if (isset($_POST)){
       //your logic here
    }
}

Comment: I think I'd still be left with the same issue though as my page template "front-page.php" would be loaded after my function, thus my function wouldn't have the up to date `$_POST` global to pass the arguments into my function, and then into `wp_query`.

Comment: Edited my main post to elaborate on the issue.